# Filtering of data according to user logged in Django app

Tags: django, tdd, filtering

I have a Django app that works well for me, but currently has no notion of user: I am the only one using it, and I would like to change this...

Except for the admin views, the logged-in user should not have access to the data created by other users. There is no shared data between users.

- I suppose I have to add a `user` foreign key to all the models I created. Correct?
- Is there a simple way to implement the filtering based on `request.user`? Can this be done more or less automatically, or do I have to go through all the code to check each and every query done on the database?
- I have written the code using TDD, and I intend to follow up...  What are the best strategies to ensure that user-filtering is implemented correctly, e.g. that I did not forget to filter an existing query?  I suppose I can write tests that show that a particular query is not yet filtered, and implement the filter.  But what about the queries that I will write later?  Is there a way I can assert that all existing and future queries return objects that only belong to the current user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to add a User FK. Don't forget you'll have to migrate your database tables - either manually, or via a tool like [South](http://south.aeracode.org/).

One way of implementing the filter would be to define custom Managers for your models, with a `for_user` method that takes the User as an argument: something like:

```
class ForUserManager(models.Manager):
    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)
```

Now you can use this manager - subclassed and/or with a mixin as necessary - on all your models, and remember to use `objects.for_user(request.user)` everywhere.

This will make testing easier too - your test could monkeypatch that `for_user` method so that it sets a flag or a counter in a global variable somewhere, and then test that it has incremented as expected.

**Edit in response to comment** No, as you suspect, that won't work. It's not even that everyone will necessarily get the last-logged-in user: it's that Managers are class-level attributes, and as such are reused throughout a process, so any request served by that server process will use the same one.

Comment: I can imagine the following: when the user logs in, I create an instance of a Manager subclass that (1) stores the `user` and (2) uses it to filter the queryset in `get_query_set`. Then I install this manager as the default one for my models.  Will this work with several different users?  Or would all users see the objects for the last connected user?
The latter, I'm afraid...